# Challenges in Bandwidth in Common mode Choke Modeling

Tags: impedance-matching, s-parameters, vna, optimization, common-mode-choke

I'm currently working on characterizing a common mode choke (CMC). However, I'm encountering difficulties aligning the bandwidth of my model with the measured results. Specifically, when I attempt to adjust parameters such as RCore, I observe changes primarily in impedance without significant improvement in bandwidth alignment. Similarly, modifying capacitance (C) results in frequency shifts and impedance changes, but fails to yield similarities with the measured data. Even after exploring variations in inductance (L), the alignment issue persists. I'm beginning to wonder if there might be an issue with my schematic. Should I consider adding or removing any parameters to address this discrepancy?[image: Schematic]
(The measured S4P file is from TDK, with part number= ACT1210G-800-2P-TL05)

LCore=83.5 µH

Rcore=20.4286 kΩ

Capacitance= 221.429 fF

[ACT1210G-800-2P-TL05](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/info?part_no=ACT1210G-800-2P-TL05)
[image: Zcommon Mode]

How can I improve this schematic for common mode impedance?

Edited..................

[image: CMC EQUIVALENT CKT]

**RESULT**

[image: Z parameter]

But the measurements didn't match the circuit as expected, so I tweaked the capacitance (parallel to coupled inductors), and I got a good match at 220 fF.

[image: C sweeping]:Figure: C Tuned from 22fF TO 220 fF

**(Red Graph: Schematic Z COMMON, Green Graph: Measured Schematic)**

[image: Zcommon]

But still, the graphs are not matched.

Comment: Did you look at TDK's published equivalent circuit model.          https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/technicalsupport/tvcl/pdf/cmf_automotive_signal_act1210g_ecm.pdf - in particular I think that the L1/C1/C4 components might change the shape of the curve a little.

Comment: Hey Robin, Thanks for the comment!........ YES, I tried to do simulation using the published equivalent diagram.  not finding any difference by sweeping L/C1/C4.  But why do you think that L1/C1/C4 ( Leakage inductance /Parasitic capacitance/ Intrawinding capacitance)  can make a difference in bandwidth? can you please explain?

Comment: Please show the actual real measurement circuit used and an image of the set-up.

Comment: Looking at the values, I agree that C4 is probably not going to do anything, but isn't your common mode signal "seeing" the reactance of L1/C1 ... I would expect that to change the shape of the curve ... unless of course for some reason the 4 repeated groups effectively cancel each other out somehow?   TDK included them in the equivalent circuit to give 6 RLC groups; your circuit has 2 RLC groups.

Comment: Edit: I have built the spice model in circuitlab and I get a completely different curve - so not sure if they are actually correct at all ?   You are welcome to take a look at it though:  https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/rgb5v3vecb2x/tdkact1210g/

Comment: @RobinIddon Can you comment on how we can predict the Imp vs f curve for a CMC considering the parameters of the equivalent model? (you can say slopes, dip in the curve, peaks)

Comment: @RobinIddon I tried to simulate the circuit in CST Studio but the result is showing the same bandwidth issues. I will edit the question again including those results, please review!

Comment: Your findings are similar to mine.  I think there are two issues here.  Firstly the TDK equivalent circuit parameters that are published seem to be wrong.  If you are a customer then you should ask them to confirm.   Secondly the s4p file is measured on a VNA while the spice model is just that, a model.  There are second order effects that aren't in the model. K and L might actually be frequency dependent.  Perhaps it just isn't easily possible to get a model that fits perfectly.  How close do you need it, and why?